# Union element alignment

Tags: c, alignment, unions

If I have a union, C standard guarantees that the union itself will be aligned to the size of the largest element.

```
union U {
    long l;
    int i;
    short s;
    char c[2];
} u;
```

But what does it say about alignment of individual union elements inside the union? Is the following expression guaranteed to be true?

```
(&u.l == &u.i) && (&u.i == &u.s) && (&u.s == &u.c[0])
```

Comment: a reminder to keep in mind what the standard does NOT say `u.i&0xFF == u.c[0]` or the low order byte of i isn't guaranteed to be c[0] (endianness)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The start of each element is aligned with the address of the union itself.

<del>so the individual comparisons in the expression you ask about are true, but the expression as a whole is false unless the union is located at address 0x0001.</del>

*The deleted text applied to the following comparisons*:

```
&u.l == &u.i == &u.s == &u.c[0]
```

*The revised version compares distinct pointer types - the pointers should be cast to void pointers.*

---

I was asked to quote the standard - or identify the section of the standard.

C99 - section 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers (paragraph 14):

> A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bitfield, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

Comment: Can you reference the relevant portion of the standard please?