# How could I compare C/C99 specifications to C++ specifications?

Tags: c++, c, standards, specifications, c99

I need to verify that I can use unions a certain way.

For C99, this answer is adequate: [Union element alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891471/union-element-alignment)

> C99 - section 6.7.2.1 Structure and
>   union specifiers (paragraph 14):
>
> A pointer to a union object, suitably
>   converted, points to each of its
>   members (or if a member is a bitfield,
>   then to the unit in which it resides),
>   and vice versa.

Can someone please help me find the equivalent guarantee for C++?

More generally, is there a good source for finding section/paragraph citations for C++ standards which are equivalent to a known feature in C?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ (14882:2003), this is split between two paragraphs:

**9.5[class.union]/1**

> Each data member is allocated as if it
>   were the sole member of a struct.

**9.2[class.mem]/17**

> A pointer to a POD-struct object,
>   suitably converted using a
>   reinterpret_cast, points to its
>   initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.

I haven't heard of a cross-reference between C and C++ like that, it may be non-trivial, as this example shows.

Comment: Good citation.  More generally, C++ was based on C specifically so it could be interoperable not just as the source level but at the binary data-handling level too.  We can *expect* C++ union/struct padding/alignment/layout to match the equivalent C compiler (or C-only mode of the compiler).  It's not worth researching every little aspect, especially as there are meaningful lists of the differences between C and C++ that really do bite during porting/interoperation.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you want to check the C++ standard, unfortunately it is not available for free. You must pay a fee to get a copy of the standard. However, the final draft (the one before the approval) is available online: for C++99 http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/, for C++0x http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf.

Comment: N3092 is a year old already (March 26, 2010), try N3242 (February 28, 2011) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf